# Python/Jython: If substring in string always results in TypeError: string member test needs char left operand

Tags: python, string, list, filter, jython

I have a list that looks like this:

```
wsadmin>print jvmLines
['', 'Stats name=jvmRuntimeModule, type=jvmRuntimeModule#', '{', 'name=HeapSize, ID=1, description=The total memory (in KBytes) in the Java virtual machine run time., unit=KILOBYTE, type=BoundedRangeStatistic, lowWaterMark=1048576, highWaterMark=1048576, current=1048576, integral=0.0, lowerBound=1048576, upperBound=2097152', '', 'name=FreeMemory, ID=2, description=The free memory (in KBytes) in the Java virtual machine run time., unit=KILOBYTE, type=CountStatistic, count=176789', '', 'name=UsedMemory, ID=3, description=The amount of used memory (in KBytes) in the Java virtual machine run time., unit=KILOBYTE, type=CountStatistic, count=871786', '', 'name=UpTime, ID=4, description=The amount of time (in seconds) that the Java virtual machine has been running., unit=SECOND, type=CountStatistic, count=3809648', '', 'name=ProcessCpuUsage, ID=5, description=The CPU Usage (in percent) of the Java virtual machine., unit=N/A, type=CountStatistic, count=1', '}']
```

Why does this:

```
for line in jvmLines:
    if "name=" in line:
        print line
```

Lead to this?

```
TypeError: string member test needs char left operand
```

I also get the same if I try lambda functions or a filter()

Comment: Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: I vaguely remember having seen this in Python 1.x or so...

Comment: @SvenMarnach Indeed you can find some [forum posts](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2000-August/002014.html) from year *2000* mentioning this. Seer: What python/jython version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, its fairly old I believe. Its the implementation of jython that comes with WebSphere 8.5.5. Even though its the very latest release of WebSphere, it still comes with a ten year old python!

Comment: I looked into this some more. WebSphere comes with Jython 2.1 (just type `sys.version` to verify). Look at SourceForge and behold, it was released in September 2002, thus why we have to deal with stupid issues from over a decade ago: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jython/files/jython/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try the `find()` method

```
for line in jvmLines:
    if line.find('name=') >= 0:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this message because I had a single value returning instead of an array.
i.e.

```
# Causes Error
# serverList = {'default': 'server001'}
if s in serverList[‘default’]

# Works Fine
# serverList = {'default': ('server001', 'server002')} 
if s in serverList[‘default’]
```

When the value returned is a list like I had expected it works fine but if it's a single value the 'in' throws an error.